# Repository to download Xen Hypervisor

Tags: xen

I'm trying to install Xen hypervisor by command, but everytime I followed instruction on internet its returned with this error

> E: Unable to locate package xen-hypervisor

I have tried to find repositories for Xen Hypervisor but failed, every instruction just told me to type sudo apt get install xen-hypervisor. Does anyone know how to add repositories that contained Xen hypervisor?

Answer (score 0):

The apt command has a search function:

```
 apt search xen
```

That gives you a long list of items including the correct package. Also you can use "apt show"
apt show xen             # now press the TAB key
That will give you

```
apt show xen-hypervisor-4.16.amd64
```

Well, it took 2 Tabs. This package is on my 22.04. Thats where the hypervisor is. But to get going with xen you probably also need bridge-utils, openswitch-switch and xen-tools.

hope it helps